# Why does spotify not block the gnome session when playing music?

Tags: gnome, session, spotify

I am a bit curious that spotify does not block the gnome session when playing music by default. Is there a way to make it blocking?

Edit: The term I was looking for was 'inhibiting' (as e.g. YouTube videos do) and not 'blocking'. I'm sorry.

Comment: It's a useful feature of Spotify that Spotify doesn't block or inhibit the session when playing music by default. Some Spotify users like to play music from Spotify as background music while they're showing there own photos, videos or streaming from their computer. Why would Spotify want to discontinue a feature that their users like?

Comment: @karel he didn't suggest they should discontinue this feature. Your questioning a senseless premis noone assumed. They could implement it as an option.